# Would asking about Christian states be considered on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

It's Christmas time, and of course every Christmas there are always cases of people filing human rights disputes about "Separation of Religion and State" and not posting "Merry Christmas" signs and notices in public places.

I was dwelling upon the [paradox](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/6532/is-there-separation-of-religion-and-state-in-canada) of the holiday season in Canada with Canadians confusing our charter with the USA Bill of Rights, and much to the satisfaction of my pride as a Canadian took special notice of this phrase at the beginning of the Canadian charter of rights and freedoms:

> [CANADIAN CHARTER OF RIGHTS AND FREEDOMS](http://www.canlii.org/en/ca/laws/stat/schedule-b-to-the-canada-act-1982-uk-1982-c-11/latest/schedule-b-to-the-canada-act-1982-uk-1982-c-11.html)
>
> Whereas **Canada is founded upon principles that recognize the
>   supremacy of God** and the rule of law:

So unlike countries such as the USA whose President has straight out [declared](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmC3IevZiik), "We are no longer a Christian nation..." (to be fair he summed up, "at least not *just*") Canada is a country that is ruled by a Christian Monarch who also acts as the Supreme governor of the mother church of the Anglican Communion. We sing in our National Anthem:

> "**God** keep our Land, Glorious and free."

So I think it's pretty solidly established that Canada is a Christian country.

**Would it be on topic to ask what other countries in the world have Christian Charters or Constitutions?**

Answer (score 4):

First two thoughts.

1. I don't think a bunch of "God" talk makes a "solidly Christian state". Expect to have to define your terms better than that!
2. I think any possible questions along these lines would benefit from a little isolation of their own. Don't mix Christmas and political issues in with questions about charters and definitions of Christian states.

Otherwise I don't see a problem with the topic. It's topical enough and if you define the scope and keep them focused I don't see a reason they wouldn't be alright.

Answer (score 3):

I think as long as you can define your terms well it should be fine. Maybe use a qualification like "Head of state is *de jure* head of a religious denomination", "founding document mentions Christianity, or makes an unmistakably Christian reference".… something like that approach should be OK.

Comment: Yeah countries whose heads of state are heads of a Christian denomination would be a really interesting question!